# why do we need socket name when there is port number?

Tags: mysql, c, mysql-connector

I am using `c` to communicate with `mysql`

it uses [`mysql_real_connect()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) to connect to DB engine.

I am just curious about knowing **"why this function require socket name and port number both?"**.
Can we not use only port number to communicate with `mysql`.

I googled for it but couldn't find any answer.
Sorry for such a childish question.

Comment: Visit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, obviously. You supply one or the other, depending on the protocol chosen by the value of the 'host' parameter, as described in the document you cited.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using named pipes or domain sockets then the socket name specifies the pipe or socket name. Otherwise, you can just pass 0 as the name.